# JSR 303 - defined size or null

Tags: java, validation, annotations, valdr, valdr-bean-validation

I have following field with `JSR-303` validation:

```
@Size(min = 6, max = 6, message = "Field needs to be 6 characters")
private String field;
```

Requirement for the field is to be `6 characters or null`.

(*I then use `valdr-bean-validation` (https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr-bean-validation) to extract it to valdr format and use in AngularJS.*)

**Question:**
How can I met requirements, using JSR-303, so that the field can be `null or 6 characters`? At the moment my `@Size` rule expects at least 6 characters.

I don't want to use custom validator, because of compatibility with valdr. Is a regex good option? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, you should use @Pattern annotation on this field (or create your own annotation with both Size, Pattern and any other rules combination)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it using `@Pattern` annotation with simple RegEx:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^.{6,6}$|^$", message = "Field must be 6 digits or empty")
private String field;
```